# Plane Identification (Coast Guard, Air Force base region)

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, airplane

I live in Clearwater Florida and multiple times a day, I have giant multi-prop Coast Guard planes, ans choppers flying low over my home.

However, today as I sat outside, I heard one but it sounded a bit different.

When I looked up, I expected to see the White with red Coast Guard "Super Hercules" flying low over us ... but the plane I seen was different.

First off, it's elevation was lower than average.

But the big difference was color. It appeared a dark gray with what looked like a red symbol on its side and tail. (Almost like a circular shape of letters painted over each other in one single spot.)

It had 4 props, and I usually get a picture of things like this, but I was shocked... I thought "Maybe a special Coast Guard plane took off out of Clearwater base?" Then I thought "Ahhhh... must be an Air Force Plane from MacDill... ?" However, they rarely send up large planes west of the base at such a low altitude.

So, I spent too much time wishing I snapped a picture as I went down a rabbit hole searching the web for answers. So now I'm here. Lol

TL;DR Dark grey/black 4 prop (like a Coast Guard Super Herc) plane with a single red symbol on its side and tail flying low , due west, as if it launched from Clearwater Coast Guard base. It definitely wasn't the usual white CG or grey AF plane color

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: High wing or low wing? conventional tail? Please tell us more about the physical characteristics.

Comment: AC130's are dark gray, but I couldn't find a red marking on any of the images I saw online. There's a unit based in Crestview, FL.

Comment: @PeterKämpf it was a low wing. I wonder if it was a private plane. It looked nearly identical to the big Coast Guard Planes... I was just like "???" Like if you go to drink an iced tea, but it's root beer .. but for the eyes. I was just kinda shocked

Comment: @RetiredATC yeah, it was a darker grey, and smaller than an AC130. I wonder if it was a private plane, or one from a movie set or something. It seemed almost comical, like my eyes were playing tricks on me.

Comment: "almost comical" is a strange way to describe a plane. Did it look like a [P-3 Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-3_Orion) maybe?